# How best to make a link submit a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

What's the best way to get a regular anchor (`<a href="...">`) to submit the form it is embedded in when clicked?

```
<form>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>
                The link could be <span>embedded <a href="" onclick="?">at any level</a></span>
                in the form, so "this.parentNode.parentNode..." is no good. :(
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

I know that the easiest way using jQuery would be

```
$('#myLink').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
});
```

...but I'm trying to find a way to do this without using a library.

---

**Edit**: I'm really trying to find a method which doesn't require knowledge of the form (eg: its name, id, etc). This would be similar to how you could put this on an input element: `<input onclick="this.form.submit()" />`

Comment: Don't do that. Use a `<button type="submit">` styled as a link. It's semantically correct, the browser does it for you, and it doesn't fail with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: you're right, that would be a better solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

loop through parent nodes until you find an element with tagname that indicates it's a form!

```
<form>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>
                The link could be <span>embedded <a href="" onclick="get_form(this).submit(); return false">at any level</a></span>
                in the form, so "this.parentNode.parentNode..." is no good. :(
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>



<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function get_form( element )
    {
        while( element )
        {
            element = element.parentNode
            if( element.tagName.toLowerCase() == "form" )
            {
                //alert( element ) //debug/test
                return element
            }
        }
        return 0; //error: no form found in ancestors
    }
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Hi hasen, i've used your method and works perfectly, i have only a question for that solution. If i want to modify the form fileds before sending(e.g. crypting) is there any way to do it? I mean i want to crypt username and password fields' values before submitting, is it possible in this function?

Comment: @Alper, the `get_form` will return the form object, check out the api: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_form.asp

Answer (score 29):

Why don't you use an `<input>` or `<button>` element and just tweak it with CSS? Then it works without Javascript and is therefore more reliable.

Comment: You can't do button:hover on IE6.

Comment: button/input-submit behaves better, more like the thing you are trying to model, so it's a better choice even if JS is guaranteed available. href="#" will behave strangely if you eg. middle-click it, right-click-bookmark etc. If hover on IE6 is actually important you can always put a JS hack in.

Comment: Agree with this answer. Links are meant to be GET requests, and there's no reason to change it. Don't make links do POST. Use form submits instead.

Comment: yeah, it's not the answer to the question though, is it? I know that you can use an input to submit a form and that it's semantically better, etc, but I wanted to know about a regular <a> link.

Comment: See other, very good, answers then. Sorry if mine is not helpful for you. Problem is, what you want to do is considered "evil". :D

Comment: nickf, sometimes the correct answer is that the question is wrongheaded.

Comment: Have posted the html / css I came up with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313478/how-best-to-make-a-link-submit-a-form/6358839#635883 since I couldn't find an example on here, if anyone has any improvements will update

Answer (score 20):

The simplest way to do that would be use something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.formName.submit();">
```

Comment: I would change that to:

<a href="#" onclick="document.formName.submit(); return false;">

The reason for the change is that although it's not supposed to happen, it's entirely possible that a browser might end up redirecting to the # link before the form is submitted, thereby screwing things up.

Comment: this is what i've ended up using, but was really hoping for a way to do it without needing to know anything about the form (eg, its name)

Answer (score 14):

I am using this now every time.  Because the submit button in my project usually a link (by wrap an image or CSS), so I use this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit(); return false;">Submit</a>
```

Don't forget it is using jQuery too.

You can wrap in your own function.  So it always submit the parent element (form) on that link.

Answer (score 12):

As long as the link is a direct child of the form, you can use this. You don't need to know the name of the form. Works in at least Firefox and Chrome.

```
<form action="">
    <a href="" onclick="parentNode.submit();return false;">Submit</a>
</form>
```

quirksmode.org tells me x.parentNode works in all browsers, so this *should* work everywhere.

Comment: Is there a way to get the parent parentNode up two levels ?

Answer (score 6):

Turn a submit button into a link using markup like this:

```
<input id="submitlink" type="submit" value="Text" />
```

And CSS like this:

```
input#submitlink {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #034af3;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

input#submitlink:visited {
    color: #505abc;
}

input#submitlink:hover {
    color: #1d60ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

input#submitlink:active {
    color: #12eb87;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

best way is

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();return false;">Submit Form</a>
```

however you probably DON'T want to do that as it will make submitting impossible for users with JS disabled

Comment: You could put a <noscript> with the submit button. Users with JS enabled will see the link with its pretty hover, and users with JS disabled will see a standard button -without hover in IE6, of course.

Comment: Didn't think of that, in fact you may want to not even have the link in HTML, just add it programmatically via JS so that they won't see it all all without JS enabled

Answer (score 1):

Similar [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313478/how-best-to-make-a-link-submit-a-form#313624) to [hasen j](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35364/hasen-j), but using a recursive function to traverse the document.

```
function findParentForm(element) {
    if (element.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'html') {
        throw('No Parent Form Found');
    } else if (element.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'form') {
        return element.parentNode;
    } else {
        return findParentForm(element.parentNode);
    }
}
```

And the form, of course...

```
<form>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>
                The link could be <span>embedded <a href="" onclick="findParentForm(this).submit(); return false;">at any level</a></span>
                in the form, so "this.parentNode.parentNode..." is no good. :(
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: is there a reason why you'd use recursion instead of a loop? isn't the overhead going to be larger with recursion? (obviously negligible at this level, but still?)

Comment: Not sure about the efficiency.  Wouldn't be hard to test with firebug.    I wrote this example before I saw hasan j's answer.  I was surprised his worked (tested it to be sure) and glad to have learned something, but figured I'd post mine as well anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer to use the `javascript:` protocol in the href instead of using onclick event... If there is any issues with this, I would be happy to be corrected.

If you have only one form in the page, a quite common case, you can do simply:

```
<li><p><a href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();">Click here to submit</a></p></li>
```

Otherwise, bubbling up the elements as above is a solution.

[EDIT] I keep the answer, even if it is downvoted, as a reference (the info given in comments is interesting).
Another drawback of the protocol technique: it doesn't generate an event object. Not a problem in the snippet I gave, but annoying when calling a handler.

Comment: what is with documents.forms[0]? Won't that be completely wrong should there be more than one form on the page before this one?

Comment: That's what I wrote: it is reliable only if you are sure to have only one form.

Comment: The javascript pseudo-protocol can trigger unexpected behavior (commonly no new images/dead script thread), it has security issues on IE in HTTPS mode, failure to include a return may redirect to strange places (try "javascript:document.body.style.display='block';"). It also fails for non-JS users.

Comment: @Borgar: thanks for the head ups, it is interesting. So outside of https and expressions with values (which I avoid also, like for bookmarklets), it should be OK... Failing for non-JS users is also true for the other form, anyway.

Comment: The reason for the lack of an event on javascript: click is that the browser thinks that you are navigating away from the page and therefore shuts services down. To avoid this mess, I recommend sticking to onclick (except in the case of bookmarklets). :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a button (and input or button of type submit) to submit a form.

If you need any additional features that a link has but input elements don't have (such as hover), then it is easier to implement those with javascript, than it is the submission of the form. It will also degrade more gracefully for people without javascript.

You can even solve this with MSIE specific code (and use :hover for other browsers):

```
<input type="submit" value="send" class="linkstyles"
       onmouseenter="this.className+=' hovered';"
       onmouseleave="this.className=this.className.replace(/(^|\s)hovered(\s|$)/g, '');" />
```

If you still really really want to do it backwards then here's how I wouldn't do it:

```
function submitByLink ( elm ) {
  // Move up domtree until we hit no parentNode or find a form
  while (elm) {
    elm = elm.parentNode;
    if (elm && elm.tagName == 'FORM') {
      // First chance we get, we submit the form and exit.
      // The return on the node it kills the event bubble by forwarding false to browser
      elm.submit(); 
      return false;
    }
  }
  // If we got here then there is no form parent and user will be sent to link href
}
```

And the HTML would look like this:

```
<a href="aPageExplainingWhyYouNeedJavascript.html" onclick="return submitByLink(this);">Send</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('#submit').click(function(){$('#signup').submit();});});
```

Using Jquery, we check the document has loaded, then we wait for an anchor tag with an id of 'submit' to be clicked. It then submits the form with an id of 'signup'. Change 'submit' and 'signup' to suit.

Answer (score 1):

To follow on from the answer above [How best to make a link submit a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313478/how-best-to-make-a-link-submit-a-form/313480#313480), the way I've been doing it recently is

```
<button class="submit" type="submit"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Link Text</a></button>
```

and CSS

```
.submit {
    background: transparent;
    border:0;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.submit a 
{
    color: #CEA249;
}
.submit:hover a
{
    color: white;
}
```

I posted this since I couldn't find an example of the html / css done. If anyone has any improvements will update.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
<input type="submit" id="submit" style="display:none;"/>
<a href="#" onclick="$('#submit').click();">Sample Submit Trick</a> 
</form>
```