# how to use css button to post method in a form?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I love this article 
["How to create Skype-like buttons using jQuery"](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/03/11/How-to-create-Skype-like-buttons-using-jQuery.aspx)

But the comment list is already closed so I need your help guys!

How to make this code to a form using submit method?

```
<a class="button" href="#"> 
<img src="*.png" alt="" />Add to cart</a>
```

This is the sample of my form where I want the css button to be inserted:

```
<form action="http://ww6.aitsafe.com/cf/addmulti.cfm" name="mal" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="">    
<input type="hidden" name="nocart">
<input type="hidden" name="qty1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="product1" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="price1" value="150.00">

<input type=submit value="Add to Cart" onclick="alert('Added to cart\n\nThis page will refresh');">
```

update... yehey! :)

Thank You to PCALCAO for the link [How best to make a link submit a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313478/how-best-to-make-a-link-submit-a-form)

There I found the answer of CHRIS to be very helfpful & now it's working...

Correct answer:

```
<a class="button" href="#" onclick="document.mal.submit(); return false;"> 
<img src="*.png" alt="" />Add to cart</a>
```

:)

Comment: sorry about that because I'm very new in web design & programming. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what you're trying to do there... but!

Here it is:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Read this, and you'll learn a bit about forms and submit buttons.

When you figure the simple html part out, start thinking about the CSS and JQuery.

-EDIT- 
You should really re-read that article!
For starters, it's:

```
<a class="button" href="#">
<img src="button.png" alt="" />Send info</a>
or <a href="#">cancel</a>
```

and not:

```
<class="button" a href="#"> 
<img src="*.png" alt="" />Add to cart</a>
```

"class" is an attribute of an HTML element, not an element by itself. The element here is "a" (anchor).

Comment: thanks for the reply but I want to use this cool CSS button for my form... :)

Comment: I'm sure you do! Still, the CSS is just one part of the equation, you'll still need the proper HTML (you can figure that out from the link I sent). If after that, you want a fancy schmancy CSS3 button... http://css3button.net/ Here you go! (I advice you to read a tutorial on how all that "magic" works, but this should get you on the right track).

Comment: i still can't figure it out... may you please check the article? again thanks... :)

Comment: the one I've posted here is my own code... sorry about that... :)

Comment: can you help me out? what do you think should be the code in the form to include the a class? :)

Comment: That class references a CSS. You need to create a CSS file and include it in your HTML. In that CSS file, you should put the code that the article shows (he tells you specifically about the CSS part).

Comment: thanks, did that part already and the button actually works but does not function as a "submit"/"image" input for a form... :(

Comment: I think the rest of the article explains that part. You're probably missing the JQuery part. If this solves your problem, consider accepting the answer =)

Comment: Thank You... I will accept the answer once I've solved it... may you pleeeaase please give me a sample code that would work? Thanks again... :)

Comment: What you have now is a different problem. This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313478/how-best-to-make-a-link-submit-a-form

Comment: Thank You... I've already solved it because the link you've given me... Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

I did not get you properly,but if you want to set an image as the submit button background,the modify the css to :

```
.button input[type="submit"]
    {
        background:url(*.png);
        color:#fff;
        width:80px;
    }
```

and the html form will be :

```
<div class="button">
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but i want to use the button from the article to my form... :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your code ment to be above.
I think you should look at HTML forms.

demo code:

```
<form method="get" action="post.php">
<input type="text" name="text">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks but i want to use the button from the article to my form... :(

Answer (score 0):

Try below jquery code if you want to apply css on sbmit button:

```
function setCss()
{
$(document).ready (function() {

$(":input[type=submit]" ).addClass("bigbutton");
 });
}

setCss();
```

Use below Style for button :

```
.button{
         border:0;
     background:url(images/yourimage.gif);
     font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size:12px;
     text-align:center;
     color:#FFFFFF;
     cursor:pointer;
     height:22px;
     width:80px;
     }
```

It will work for all browsers.

if you want animate then change image/style on hover using jquery function :

```
$( ":input[type=submit]" ).css( {"background": 'no-repeat url("'+baseurl+'/public/images/blue_btn1.gif")', "color": "#ffffff","width":"80px","height":"25px", "font-weight": "bold","font-family":"Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif","font-size":"12px","background":"none","border":"0"} );
```

Comment: your answer looks promising, but can you please check the article & how to implement it in a form? thanks... :)

Comment: just change image using jqury call again on hover like :$( ":input[type=submit]" ).css( {"background": 'no-repeat url("'+baseurl+'/public/images/blue_btn1.gif")', "color": "#ffffff","width":"80px","height":"25px", "font-weight": "bold","font-family":"Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif","font-size":"12px","background":"none","border":"0"} );

Comment: Try just arround these things. am sure u r close. :)

Comment: hope so... i've been figuring this out almost 3 weeks now... hehehe... Thanks... :)