# HTML using the <a> tag to process a form

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How best to make a link submit a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313478/how-best-to-make-a-link-submit-a-form)

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">
....
<a class="button" href=""><span>Buy Now</a>
</form>
```

In the above code how can I use the `<a>` tag to process the form? I don't want to use a submit button since most of my css code only recognized the  attribute.

Comment: So change the CSS. Submit buttons submit forms, it is what they are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jquery like:

```
<form id="myForm" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">
....
<a class="button" onclick="$('#myForm').submit();" href="#"><span>Buy Now</a>
</form>
```

you'll have to include jquery for this

or plain javascript:

```
<form id="myForm" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">
....
<a class="button" onclick="document.forms["myForm"].submit();" href="#"><span>Buy Now</a>
</form>
```

Comment: jQuery? For that? 32k to achieve what can be done in about a dozen bytes seems … excessive.

Comment: well, if you'll only have to use jquery for this i would go for just javascript. I edited my answer for a javascript solution as well

Comment: Thanks. I need to remember this lol.

Answer (score 2):

You could use javascript to submit your form

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fire a submit with the help of JavaScript.

```
document.getelementById("btn_submit_link").onclick = function () {
     document.forms["name-of-form"].submit();
}
```

Note that the link should have an `id` attribute, in this case `btn_submit_link`.