# Automatically Submitting a Form Using a Link

Tags: html, forms, hyperlink, onclick

I would like to use a link that takes the user to an external site and automatically hits the "submit" button on a form. Is this possible with HTML?

Comment: Is the form supposed to be submitted on the external site or on your site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How best to make a link submit a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313478/how-best-to-make-a-link-submit-a-form)

Comment: It is possible using javascript.  If you need more details on how to do it then post a more detailed question including the code that you have tried so far.